# Measure line segment length crossing one fixed point

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I'd like to measure the shortest distance between two dark portion. The distance line segment should cross the red point on the image. The black and white background are logical values. The background matrix and the red point are known (attached as [dataset.mat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hmdm59HUUvtchnTlm9fX7cWHUvS4gFxT/view?usp=sharing)). Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extract top edge and bottom edge for the dark region.
2. Get the (x, y) value of a fixed line on the bottom of the image.
3. Get the corresponding (x, y) value using the points on the fixed line and the fixed center point.
4. Use polyxpoly to find the intersection of the line segment and the dark region edge.
5. Calculate distance and find the min distance.